# Print all minimum paths between 2 nodes in an undirected weighted graph

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, undirected-graph, weighted-graph

Given an **undirected weighted graph**, the lengths between 2 nodes are integers.

How can one print the **pair of nodes** that have the **minimum distance** in the graph. If there are multiple pairs, print all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's agree that we are looking for simple paths (no repeated vertices) on a undirected weighted graph G.

The amount of minimum distance paths between two vertices *u* and *v* could be up to (n-2)! (complete graph with zero weight edges, every permutation that starts at *u* and ends at *v* is a valid minimum distance path).

Nevertheless, you can figure out the amount of such paths or do backtrack to find each of them if you manage to create a new graph G' with the same vertices as G and whose edges are those that belongs to some minimum distance path between *u* and *v* in G.

An easy way to build G' is:

1. Calculate single source shortest paths that begin at *u* and keep distance array (du).
2. Calculate single source shortest paths that begin at *v* and keep distance array (dv).
3. Create G' with all nodes from G and zero edges.
4. For each edge <*x*, *y*> in G (weight of <*x*, *y*> is *w*), if du[x] + w + dv[y] == du[v] or du[y] + w + dv[x] == du[v] then <x, y> belongs to G'.

If you force edge direction at step 4 and there are no zero weight loops then G' is DAG (directed acyclic graph). You can use DAG property to calculate amount of minimum distance path between *u* and *v* in G' and as sidequest prove such answer is equal to the answer of original problem. Also, if backtracking from *u* whenever it find *v* then you obtain a minimum distance path between *u* and *v* in G.

You can use dijkstra's algorithm or Bellman-Ford's algorithm to calculate single source shortest paths based on your weight constraints.

Comment: What will the time complexity of this be?

Comment: To build G' (and using Dijkstra's algorithm) the runtime is O(ElogV + (E + V)) since you perform 2 calls to Dijkstra O(ElogV), create G' O(V) and iterate all edges in G O(E). Usually |V| is lower or equal than |E| so total runtime is O(ElogV).

Comment: To calculate the amount of minimum distance path between u and v in a DAG the runtime used is O(V + E) (use of topological sort and dynamic programming to find the answer)

Comment: Backtracking is O(n!) as mentioned before.